# Java ArrayList with objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist

So I have this class of terms

```
public class Term {

private int coefficient ;
private int exponent ;

public Term(int coefficient, int exponent)
{
    this.coefficient = coefficient ;
    this.exponent = exponent ;
}

public int getCo()
{
    return coefficient ;
}

public int getEx()
{
    return exponent ;
}
}
```

And I have a class called Polynomial that creates an arraylist of type term with a method called delete that isn't working the way I'd like it to and I can't figure out why:

```
public class Polynomial{

public Polynomial()
{
   poly = new ArrayList<>() ;
}

public void delete (int coeff, int expo)
{

   for(int i = 0; i < poly.size(); i++) 
   {
       System.out.println("**Delete Loop works") ; //This does not print
       if( (poly.get(i).getCo() == coeff) && (poly.get(i).getEx() == expo) ) 
       {
           poly.remove(i) ;
           removed = true ;   

           break ;
       }

   }
}
}
```

It keeps throwing an exception every time I run the delete method and I'm not sure why?? I am using input from a text file (and the input is working fine), I think it might be going wrong where I use : `poly.get(i).getCo() == coeff` is that properly written?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: where I wrote `//this does not print` it doesn't even print if I write a loop that is always true. It is strange.

Comment: If that SOP does not print, then it means the *poly* arraylist is empty and has nothing to be deleted from it.

Comment: I think your `ArrayList` is empty.

Comment: at Polynomial.delete(Polynomial.java:72)
 at PolynomialTest.main(PolynomialTest.java:49)
Java Result: 1

Comment: if "System.out.println("**Delete Loop works") ;" is not printing means the array poly is zero in size. Chcek if that has anything. Also, you cannot change the array like remove from array, while iterating over it.

Comment: I think you are having concurrent modification exception. Try with an iterator us i have indicated in the answer

Comment: @DavidBaez What happens if you print something above the loop?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Polynomial` constructor, you have defined `poly = new ArrayList<>() ;` which creates ArrayList with not a single object in it.

That means `poly.size() = 0` that's why it will not enter in loop and your syso statement will not executed.

Comment: I'm using another class with a main method in it to populate the list.  :<

Comment: http://speedy.sh/cwcqs/Polynomial.java
http://www.speedyshare.com/848FJ/PolynomialTest.java `//Main Method`
http://speedy.sh/q9qp2/Term.java
http://speedy.sh/FAFZe/operations.txt

Comment: -1 The OP specifically said he is having an exception. If size is `0` there no reason for occurring an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> It keeps throwing an exception every time I run the delete method and
>   I'm not sure why??

You are probably having `ConcurrentModificationException`. The exception is thrown because you are iterating over the array list and removing an element at the same time. Try using `Iterator<T>iterator` instead and  `iterator.remove()` method.

```
   Iterator<Poly>iterator = arrayList.iterator();
   while(iterator.hasNext())
   {
       Poly poly = iterator.next();
       if( (poly.getCo() == coeff) && (poly.getEx() == expo) ) 
          iterator.remove();
    }
```